# Wagtail CMS not rendering navigation icons/images

Tags: python, django, wagtail

I've recently taken over working on a Django/Wagtail app that has a few bug that needs fixing. One of which is the icons/images in the CMS are not displaying in the menus and throughout the entire CMS, which is making navigation confusing for the users. Anyone have insights as to why fonts etc are loading, but not the icons (see image below for one example)

[Wagtial CMS Rendering Issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6HRBG.png)

Comment: 1) Make sure you've cleared your browser cache - outdated CSS is a common cause of display issues. 2) If you're hosting static files on a remote service such as Amazon S3, see the notes about CORS HTTP headers at https://docs.wagtail.io/en/stable/advanced_topics/deploying.html#cloud-storage

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, @gasman. The S3 bucket didn't have a CORS policy. So it was a CORS issue. Thanks for the nudge.